# Series of integrate in exponential

Tags: series-expansion

Why *Mathematica* cannot perform this series:

```
Series[Exp[0.5*Integrate[(I*Exp[I*x[l]] + ϵ * M2[l]),{l,0,L}]],{ϵ,0,1}]

(*Series[Exp[0.5*Integrate[(I*Exp[I*x[l]] + ϵ * M2[l),{l,0,L}]*)
```

While it can perform this:

```
  Series[Exp[0.5*Integrate[I*Exp[I*x[l]], {l, 0, L}]]*
  Exp[0.5 Integrate[ϵ*M2[l], {l, 0, L}]], {ϵ, 0, 1}]

  (*Exp[0.5*Integrate[I*Exp[I*x[l]], {l, 0, L}]] * (1+ϵ*Integrate[M2[l],{l,0,L}])*)
```

Since mathematically the two expressions are the same?

Comment: Please report your code without the box expressions to improve readability. You can for instance copy it from *Mathematica* as plain text.

Comment: Because in the first one, you're asking Mathematica to integrate an unknown function `M2[l]` which will not produce a form suitable for series. This prevents the outer series from evaluating. In the second one it works because the integral in the series can be computed entirely and the outer series accepts it. In essence, `Integrate[M2[l],{l,0,1}]` for some general `M2[l]` will not produce useful output for the outer `Series` - as your integral is too general without an explicit definition of `M2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably mean you can easily get exchanging integration and series expansion. And could also do without `Normal[]` but this way it looks better after `Simplify[].`

Here it is up to the order `eps^2`

```
Integrate[Series[
    Exp[1/2 (I*Exp[I*x[l]] + \[Epsilon]*M2[l])], {\[Epsilon], 0, 2}] // 
   Normal, {l, 0, L}] // Simplify
```

$\int_0^L \frac{1}{8} e^{\frac{1}{2} i e^{i x[l]}} \left(8+4 \epsilon  \text{M2}[l]+\epsilon ^2 \text{M2}[l]^2\right) \, dl$